# How can I squash merge when merge.ff = only?

Tags: git, merge

To start with, I have my `merge.ff` setting to `only`, as in:

```
git config --global merge.ff only
```

I have it like this because I don't want git to do non-fast-forward merges without checking with me first. This acts as a nice safeguard to make sure I get the opportunity to do something other than create an extraneous merge commit. When I do need to do a non-fast-forward merge, I can tell git to override my default setting:

```
git merge --no-ff
```

Now consider a git repository with a history like this:

[image: single diverging branch]

Let's say for some reason I want to squash merge the `work` branch onto `master`. (In a case this simple, I could just rebase, of course, but suppose I had some other reason to squash instead.) You normally do a squash merge with the `--squash` argument:

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash work
```

But in this instance, it results in an error message:

> `fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.`

This kind of makes sense. A fast-forward merge *isn't* possible because both branches have commits that are not in common. But this is also okay: I want to do a merge anyway. The obvious solution is to use `--no-ff` like I normally would to tell git that this is okay and it should proceed anyway:

```
git merge --squash --no-ff work
```

But this also gives an error:

> `fatal: You cannot combine --squash with --no-ff.`

So how do I get git to squash merge without changing my configuration?

Comment: I suppose one option is to rebase and then squash, but this seems at least redundant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Answer

Use `git -c merge.ff merge --squash <args>`.

#### Discussion

Squash "merges" are not really merges at all (and in fact, neither are fast-forward merges), so it seems like a bug that git rejects them with the config setting.

That said, though, you could temporarily override your `merge.ff=only` setting.  Experimentation shows that this works (aside, merging with `stash` is nonsensical but I happen to have one in this repo and I'm not actually merging here):

```
$ git config --global merge.ff=only
$ git merge --squash stash
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
$ git -c merge.ff=false merge --squash stash
fatal: You cannot combine --squash with --no-ff.
$ git -c merge.ff=true merge --squash stash
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
```

(at which point I just use `git reset --hard` to undo the fake merge).

Since `-c` defaults to `=true`, we get the answer at the top.

Comment: A squash merge *is* a merge in the sense that git must perform the same operations in terms of resolving different change sets (conflicts, in particular). You may have a point about fast-forward merges, since there's no conflicting set of changes to deal with by definition, but on the other hand, you could view it as a merge in the sense of bring two branches in line with each other, which still happens in a fast-forward merge. A matter of semantics, of course. I'm going to wait a little while to accept in case another answer comes along, but this does work. Thank you.

Comment: The squash-merge merges *file* changes, but the result is not a merge *commit*, hence my claim that it is not a merge at all.  I'll point out here that `git cherry-pick`, for instance, also does file merges, and in fact, `git merge --squash` has the same effect as `git cherry-pick -n <range>` (although there's only one conflict-resolve pass with the `merge` version).  Nobody seems to call the cherry-pick a merge, so why do we call "squash merge" a merge? :)  (I think the answer is "because we use a merge command to do it," which is a circular argument.)

Comment: Fair enough. I'd be the last to argue that the terminology in git is completely clear. I was more suggesting a possible reasoning of the people who named it. =)

Comment: Yes, I think git's terminology and command setup leaves a lot to be desired in many cases (some more important than others—the lack of a clear distinction between branch *name* and branch *structure-within-DAG* being probably the most egregious, but the many ways `git reset` combines different actions based on similar underlying implementation is also a strong contender...).